# PHP associative array that prints elements from 4 to 8

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

My goal is to write a php script that prints elements from 4 ("Adam =>16,) to 8 ("Kunegunda" => 42,) in an associative array. My code prints all elements. What i have to change?

```
$ages = array("Marek" => 22, "Jeacek" => 32, "Michał" => 28, "Adam" => 16, "Adrian" => 25, "Bolesław" => 9, "Jeremi" => 28, "Kunegunda" => 42, "Anna" => 40, "Elżbieta" => 96);

foreach($ages as $x => $x_value) {
  echo "Name = " . $x . ", Age = " . $x_value;
  echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a strange start situation you have here. Keep in mind that php does not guarantee the order of the array with such an associative array. It might well be that those 4 elements change when you make changes to the array, even outside that slice.

Comment: @arkascha PHP actually guarantees the order in an associative array as far as I'm informed.

Comment: assoc arrays order is based on order of insertions per the spec: https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/12-arrays.md

Answer (score 2):

get a slice from your array and loop throw it

```php
foreach(array_slice($ages, 4, 4) as $x => $x_value) {
  echo "Name = " . $x . ", Age = " . $x_value;
  echo "<br>";
}
```

array_slice will return a new array from your old array (from 4th item with 4steps forward so from 4 to 8) then the foreach wil loop the slice only (from 4 to 8)

Comment: Good suggestion, do you mind eleborating on the precise workings of the solution you provided? (As in, add a bit more explaining)

Comment: ive edited my response, hope this was helpful